# Xcode SwiftUI modify extension variable

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have an extension of Color that stores a colour variable. I am currently using this to set the main colour for the whole app, which currently works.
`extension Color{ static var colour: Color = Color.red }`
If I set it to red everything turns red. But at the moment I have to hard code what colour it will be. I want to be able to modify this colour during runtime.

I have tried to modify the extension at runtime but I can’t seem to get it working and I’m not sure if it allows you to do this. I’m not sure the best way to approach this.

If anyone has anyway of changing the variable in an extension that would be ideal but if there’s another way, any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions or I haven’t explained something clearly ask away.
Thanks so much

Comment: `Color.colour = .yellow`? What is the problem with your code, could you share the code where you try to change it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that doesn't seem to work and im not sure why. No errors are thrown it just doesnt update. The current code im using to change it `Button(action:{ Color.accent = .blue }){ Text("Change Colour") }`

Comment: Upon further testing it seems like that may actually be working it just takes a while to update. It appears to me as though it updates when another thing updates